# Django: Filtering one models records to show all records of other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm trying to filter all subjects from my model subjects, and then show all the evaluations within that subject from my other model evaluations for a specific employee which is also a model.

So when I click on a subject, which are fetched from my subject model, I want to get all the evaluations for that employee within that subject. I'm thinking each of the subjects are buttons or anchor tags that when clicked show the evaluations within that subject.

**Subject model**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   subjectname = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Indtast navnet på faget.")
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

**Evaluation model**

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   employee_num = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   subjectname = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**Employee model**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
   employee_num = models.IntegerField(help_text="Indtast medarbejderens MA-nummer. (F.eks 123456)")
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens fornavn.")
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens efternavn.")
   subjectname = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**Employee subject view**

```
class EmployeeDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'evalsys/employee/alle_employees_eval.html'
    model = Employee

    # Uses employee PK to make a detail view
    def view_employee_with_pk(self, pk=None):
        if pk:
            employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            employee = self.employee
        args = {'employee': employee, }
        return render(self, 'evalsys/employee/alle_employees_eval.html', args)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailViewDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['evaluation'] = Evaluering.objects.all()
        context['subject_list'] = Subject.objects.all()
        context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.all().filter(ma=self.object)
        return context
```

**Template**

So in my template I would have something like:

```
{% for subject in subject_list %}
    <a href="">{{ subject.subjectname }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

From that point on I don't really know how to filter things. 
Hope it makes sense, I translated and cut out irrelevant information from the code, so just ask if something does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the evaluations associated with a subject in the template by doing this:

```
{% for subject in subject_list %}
    <a href="">{{ subject.subjectname }}</a>
    {% for evaluation in subject.evaluation_set.all %}
        <span>{{ evaluation }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can do something similar for any other foreign keys.

Comment: This is great - thanks so much. Do you have any suggestions for hiding content unless the subject is clicked on? Suppose some if-statement around? Hmm

Comment: Theres one thing, doing what you said above will get me all evaluations and not filtered on the PK of the employee, how would I add it to only show the specific employee's?

Comment: You probably want to hide things based on click events with JavaScript. To get a specific employee, pass that employee in directly from the view and then use the same approach. You should not be filtering in the template.